# How to propagate keyboard event to parent in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In my Vue 3 application, I have nested components five levels deep. The top-level component, TopCom and the bottom-level component MostInnerCom both have a @keydown handler.

If MostInnerCom has focus and a key is pressed that MostInnerCom cannot handle, then that event shall be handled by TopCom. How can this be achieved?

I have created a very simple demo using nested divs instead of nested components. Please see [this small demo in codepen](https://codepen.io/hans-admiraal/pen/qBPZwQN).

Here is the relevant code snippet, which doesn't work:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const keycode = Vue.ref('')
    
    function onKeydownForApp(e) {
      keycode.value = '***'
    }
    
    function onKeydownForButton(e) {
      if (e.code === 'KeyA') {
        parent.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(e.type, e))
      } else {
        keycode.value = e.code
      }
    }

    return {
      keycode,
      onKeydownForApp,
      onKeydownForButton
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<main id="app">
  <div @keydown="onKeydownForApp" tabindex="-1">
    <input type=text>
    <div>
      <button @keydown.stop="onKeydownForButton">- K -</button>
      keycode={{keycode}}
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: have you try to add `@keydown.stop.self` ?

Comment: @DengSihan, how exactly? If I replace `@keydown.stop` with `@keydown.stop.self`, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variable `parent` refers to `window.parent`, i.e. the parent document, not the parent HTML element. A solution would be to add an id attribute to the div that surrounds the button, e.g. `<div id="parentDiv">` and then let `parent` refer to this div:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
```